# org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate object with new boolean field

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

My `Spring-Boot` & `Couchbase` app has a `Cat` object in the DB.

In a new app version, we added new boolean field to out `Cat` document object:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))
@Document
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Cat {
....
@Field
final boolean isHungry
```

But now, we already have Cat objects that are in the DB and don't have this field.

When the app is trying to read these `Cats` we get this error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed 
  to instantiate com.example.Cat using constructor public 
  com.example.Cat(...) with arguments ... 
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter isHungry must not be null!
```

Isn't there a way to tell `Spring` that if the field is missing in the DB, it should use a default value (`false` in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Try making a constructor with all parameters except `isHungry`, and set `isHungry` to false

Comment: The potential problem I see with the "add another constructor" way, is that if in the future more fields will be added to the `Cat`, we will need to have many constructors with different combinations (E.g. without `isHungry`, without `isHungry` & `favoriteToy`....)

Answer (score 1):

How about changing `isHungry` to `Boolean` and adding a getter, which will map `null` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I should be exclude annotation Builder, after this my new parameter would be initialize by false.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the object mapper to not fail on unknown properties...

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.registerModule(new JsonValueModule());

 mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

 ClusterEnvironment env = ClusterEnvironment.builder()
     .jsonSerializer(new JacksonJsonSerializer(mapper))
     .build();
```

see https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/codec/JacksonJsonSerializer.html

Note that you must add Jackson to your classpath/dependencies.